# How can I send a java project including all referenced libraries to a friend so that they can run it and edit the source in their Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to send a project that uses Selenium libraries to a friend so they can run it and edit the source code in their Eclipse IDE. From what I understand, they won't be able to edit the source if I send them a JAR file, and if I send them an archive file they'd need to import the referenced libraries themselves. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Typically, people make use of a build system (ANT, Maven, Gradle, etc). These systems allow you to specify an internet-served copy of any libraries you want to, which won't require explicitly downloading them.

Comment: If someone needs to deal with source code anyway, you could share a git or subversion repository.

Answer (score 0):

You should define all your dependencies (libraries, etc.) with tools such as maven or gradle.

While project sharing should be performed via a VCS tool like git to keep track and merge the changes both of you will make and a remote repository on GitHub or similar platforms to share and store the project.